# Powershell script to transfer files from local folder to document library

Tags: powershell

I have following code

which allows me to transfer automatically one file to sharepoint.
Is it possible to modify it the way it will upload every file from Temp to DL ? 
Thank you:

```
   # Set the variables
$WebURL = “http://contoso.com/spaces/”
$DocLibName = “Doc_DL”
$FilePath = “C:\Temp\PSW”

# Get a variable that points to the folder
$Web = Get-SPWeb $WebURL
$List = $Web.GetFolder($DocLibName)
$Files = $List.Files

# Get just the name of the file from the whole path
$FileName = $FilePath.Substring($FilePath.LastIndexOf("\")+1)

# Load the file into a variable
$File= Get-ChildItem $FilePath

# Upload it to SharePoint
$Files.Add($DocLibName +"/" + $FileName,$File.OpenRead(),$false)
$web.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found two intresting codes that resolve my issue:

## Copy Files from folder

```
if((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell") -eq $null)
{
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
}

#Script settings
$webUrl = "http://vs-server12"

$docLibraryName = "Documents"
$docLibraryUrlName = "Shared%20Documents"
$localFolderPath = "C:\temp\Docs4SharePoint"

#Open web and library
$web = Get-SPWeb $webUrl
$docLibrary = $web.Lists[$docLibraryName]
$files = ([System.IO.DirectoryInfo] (Get-Item $localFolderPath)).GetFiles()
ForEach($file in $files)
{
#Open file
$fileStream = ([System.IO.FileInfo] (Get-Item $file.FullName)).OpenRead()

#Add file
$folder =  $web.getfolder($docLibraryUrlName)

write-host "Copying file " $file.Name " to " $folder.ServerRelativeUrl "..."
$spFile = $folder.Files.Add($folder.Url + "/" + $file.Name, [System.IO.Stream]$fileStream, $true)
write-host "Success"

#Close file stream
$fileStream.Close();
}

#Dispose web

$web.Dispose()
```

And this one copy folders, subfolders and files.

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Upload-local-folder-its-7c6f6a06

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but it would be something like this:

```
# Set the variables
$WebURL = "http://contoso.com/spaces/"
$DocLibName = "Doc_DL"
$FilePath = "C:\Temp\PSW"

# Get a variable that points to the folder
$Web = Get-SPWeb $WebURL
$List = $Web.GetFolder($DocLibName)
$ListFiles = $List.Files

# Get just the name of the file from the whole path
$FileName = $FilePath.Substring($FilePath.LastIndexOf("\")+1)

# Load the file into a variable
$Files = Get-ChildItem $FilePath

# Upload it to SharePoint
foreach($File in $Files){
  $ListFiles.Add($DocLibName +"/" + $FileName,$File.OpenRead(),$false)
}
$web.Dispose()
```

Comment: Unfortunitly notI'v git error: a file with the name Doc_DL already exist

Comment: again, it was untested, but that should be the structure, you might have to change the $false parameter to $true

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use PnP PowerShell, you can handle multiple auth scenarios over there including MFA (multi factor authentication)

This link might help: https://thenikhilk.com/2020/08/30/upload-to-sharepoint/

It has two versions of PowerShell scripts which even takes care of MFA (2FA)

It only takes a few parameters, you can even use it in your pipelines or automation and it supports all SharePoint versions

- Online
- 2019
- 2016
- 2013