# Upload large set of documents converting folder names to tags

Tags: file-upload, tagging

In general, I have a large library of files on a network drive and am trying to find the best way to upload them to a SharePoint library.  I'd like to avoid any folders, but retain the metadata of the folder structure.  Conceptually, I'd like to just convert the filepath to a series of tag, where a tag is created for each folder the file sits under.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

There is no application for this, but you can create application/script where you will split the Path to Folder Names and fill Metadata with it.
[You can use this application](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/208425/powershell-script-to-transfer-files-from-local-folder-to-document-library) add only [updating of metadata](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/121663/update-document-properties-in-library-using-csom) (metadata are updated after the file is created on SharePoint)

Comment: From what I understand, the ability to edit metadata is different for each file type, which might make this impractical (most are microsoft suite or PDF, but not all, and some of the microsoft files are older and so aren't zipped xmls).  Any thoughts on doing the tagging after they have been uploaded into a custom column or something?  Or maybe my assumption is wrong.